# Filter array of objects - erase last word in the string

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I have an array of objects:

```
[
   {
      barcode: ""
      description: "META AM 29 XX Edition Large"
      description2: ""
      group: "COM20"
   },

   {,
      barcode: ""
      description: "META AM 29 TEAM Large"
      description2: ""
      group: "COM20"
   }
]
```

I want to get rid of the last word in the description. So the result would be:

```
[
   {
      barcode: ""
      description: "META AM 29 XX Edition"
      description2: ""
      group: "COM20"
   },

   {,
      barcode: ""
      description: "META AM 29 TEAM"
      description2: ""
      group: "COM20"
   }
]
```

I am using filter, but I don't understand why it doesn't work:

```
var filtered = data.filter((val) => {
   return val.description.replace(/\w+[.!?]?$/, '');
})
console.log(filtered)
```

The log is the exactly same array without any change.

Comment: You have to use the ```map``` function, not the ```filter``` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```js
let data = [{
    barcode: "",
    description: "META AM 29 XX Edition Large",
    description2: "",
    group: "COM20"
  },

  {
    barcode: "",
    description: "META AM 29 TEAM Large",
    description2: "",
    group: "COM20"
  }
]

let result = data.map(ele => {
  let lastword = ele.description.lastIndexOf(" ");
  ele.description = ele.description.substring(0, lastword);


  return ele;


});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Please accept if it works @LukasLukeStateczny thanks

Comment: Will do in 3 min ;). Won't let me yet

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `map`:

```
var result = data.map(({description, ...rest}) => {
   description: description.replace(/\w+[.!?]?$/, '')
   , ...rest 
})
```

An example:

```js
let arr = [
    {
       barcode: "",
       description: "META AM 29 XX Edition",
       description2: "",
       group: "COM20"
    }, 
    {
       barcode: "",
       description: "META AM 29 TEAM",
       description2: "",
       group: "COM20"
    }
 ]

 const result = arr.map(({description, ...rest}) => ({
description : description.replace(/\w+[.!?]?$/, ''),
 ...rest,

 }))

 console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `map`

```js
const data = [{"barcode":"","description":"META AM 29 XX Edition Large","description2":"","group":"COM20"},{"barcode":"","description":"META AM 29 TEAM Large","description2":"","group":"COM20"}];

var filtered = data.map((val) => {
  let obj = val;
  obj.description = obj.description.replace(/\w+[.!?]?$/, "");
  return obj;
});
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: you missing last space.

Comment: you can use  ` \w+$` as regex.

Answer (score 0):

Using sweet ES6 way, clean and neat solution.

**Using index:**

```js
const data = [{"barcode":"","description":"META AM 29 XX Edition Large","description2":"","group":"COM20"},{"barcode":"","description":"META AM 29 TEAM Large","description2":"","group":"COM20"}];
const format = (data) =>
  data.map(({ description = "", ...rest }) => ({
    ...rest,
    description: description.substring(0, description.lastIndexOf(" ")),
  }));
console.log(format(data));
```

**Using split:**

```js
const data = [{"barcode":"","description":"META AM 29 XX Edition Large","description2":"","group":"COM20"},{"barcode":"","description":"META AM 29 TEAM Large","description2":"","group":"COM20"}];
const format = (data) =>
  data.map(({ description = "", rest }) => ({
    ...rest,
    description: description.split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" "),
  }));
console.log(format(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

It works too:

```
let arr = [
    {
        barcode: "",
        description: "META AM 29 XX Edition Large",
        description2: "",
        group: "COM20",
    },

    {
        barcode: "",
        description: "META AM 29 TEAM Large",
        description2: "",
        group: "COM20",
    }
];


let result = arr.map(item => {
    item.description = item.description.replace(/[ ](?=[^ ]*$)\w+[.!?]?\s?$/, '');
    return item;
});

console.log(result);
```